# Dynatrace Application detection

Tags: java, glassfish, dynatrace

we recently started using Dynatrace monitoring. We are using GlassFish as application container. Dynatrace is able to identify the services running on GlassFish, but for all hosts it just displays a single application called "My Web App". Is there a way to automatically mark the processes as an Application? Should we put some additional tags on the deployed EARs?

Answer (score 1):

We found the way to define and separate the Applications in Dynatrace.

Go to Settings/ Web and mobile monitoring/ Application Rules/ Create custom grouping rules

You can define Applications based on the URL or Domain.

I hope this helps